# How to change the default keybind for accepting IntelliSense / Copilot suggestion in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I have installed VS 2022 and Github Copilot. When there is a code recomandation, it suggests to press `TAB` to accept the suggestion, but I want to assign another key for this and leave the `TAB` for inserings actual TABs in the code.

[image]

I have tried to change a few bindings from `Options > Environment > Keyboard` but none seems to affect this one.

Is there any way to change this action's key to something else ?

Comment: This. This is actually the reason I'm not using copilot :(

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76462551/11107541

Comment: Funny, I want the opposite (tab to accept the suggestion) so it works the same as VS Code, but tab does not work -- it inserts a tab -- and I have to press the right arrow to accept the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press copilot icon in the right bottom corner.
2. Select `Edit Keyboard Shortcuts...`
3. In the search field, change `copilot` to `accept inline suggestion`
4. Double-tap on the line "Accept Inline Suggestion"
5. Choose the keybinding you want.

> After this, copilot's suggestion will be remapped to the keybinding of your choice. And `TAB` will either insert actual `TAB` (default 4 spaces) or accept suggestion from IntelliSense if there is one.

P.S. If you want to also disable accepting Intellisense suggestions on `TAB`, follow the same procedure, but instead of `accept inline suggestion` use `acceptSelectedSelection` (one that has a `TAB` as a keybinding).