# VS Code suggestion widget and inline suggestions conflict

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, tabnine

I have had this issue since I started using Tabnine for VS Code.
I added inline suggestion mode in VS Code and it conflicts with the suggestion panel.

I want my VS Code to work as follows:
When typing stuff, hitting `tab` autocomplete Tabnine and hitting `enter` insert first pre-selected item in IntelliSense (suggestion panel).

My current situation:
Because the first item in the suggestion panel is not pre-selected, hitting `enter` will go to the next line, and hitting `tab` will auto-complete Tabnine inline suggestions.
Here is a screenshot of my editor when the first item is not pre-selected.

[image]

When hitting `arrow down` key, it will select the first item, and then hitting `enter` will insert the first item.

Some of my editor settings:

```json
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never"
 "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you set `"editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never"` in order to "enable tab for tabnine"? But in doing so you made it so you have to manually use arrow keys to focus a suggestion.

I'd instead suggest just unbinding tab from accepting a selected suggestion. Ex. like this in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```

And then you can remove your `"editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never"` to let it go back to the default value of `"always"`.

---

Actually, another thing you could try is to put `"editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions": true` in your settings.json file. The setting's description:

> Controls how inline suggestions interact with the suggest widget. If enabled, the suggest widget is not shown automatically when inline suggestions are available.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said, but now sometimes tabnine inline suggestion does not suggest anything, and hitting `tab` will just add 2 spaces or just autocomplete it badly. and when tabnine does give me suggestions and at the same time the first item in the suggestion panel is selected,  it also just adds two spaces. is there any way when tabnine doesn't give a suggestion, hitting `tab` or `enter` inserts the first suggestion from the panel, and when it does give an inline suggestion hitting `tab` insert tabnine? it is very confusing....!!! @starball

Comment: @AmirMeimari Not that I'm aware of with the method I suggested here. To get that, VS Code would have to support extensions [contributing](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points) [when-clause contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts), which- as far as I'm aware- it doesn't. But if it did, then you could write a keybinding that only binds tag to accept suggestion outside of the tabnine inline suggestion when-clause. Is this solution sufficient for you?

Comment: Not sure, however, I removed `"editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never"` and went with a more "default" approach. this way it does make more sense. I guess your answer is partially right so I'll accept it. thanks for your time mate!

Comment: @AmirMeimari see edit for something else you could try.