# Give copilot suggestions priority on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Im starting to use copilot on vscode and i find that sometimes other vscode prompts come first than copilots suggestions. I disabled abc and that helped but im still not quite happy.
I use primarily HTML (pug), scss and javascript.

I tried:

- installing copilot as instructed in docs
- disabling abc suggestions
- searched the settings on vs

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462765/11107541 help?

Comment: i think not @starball, the user there described having both suggestion methods working at the same time but not being able to select his preferred option as he wanted. 
My problem is i only get vscode suggestions unless i press esc and close that dialog. Only then i see copilot suggestion.