# How can I know if a vscode intelliSense suggestion is visible?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions, code-completion

I am creating an inline code completion plugin for vscode.

I am using the InlineCompletionItemProvider to show the inline suggestions.

However, I am making the call to generate suggestion even when an IntelliSense popup is visible. This is an unnecessary call for me as the suggestion I have will not be visible until and unless the user closes the intelliSense popup. I want to reduce this unnecessary cost.

Is there a way to identify whether intelliSense popup is visible or not. So that I can not call inline completions when the popup is visible.

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean it won't be visible? I was under the impression that this was something to be left up to the user. see the `editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions` setting, which I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462765/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This would be another case where a `getContext()` api would be useful - to get current context keys.  Because there is a `suggestWidgetVisible` context key.  Unfortunately the request for `getContext()` has been mostly shut down.  See [add getContext command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/118722).

But you can add your use case here: [Lift setContext from a command to proper API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10471) which remains open apparently just for `getContext()` since `setContext()` has been implemented.